# iOS 10 UserNotification Framework. Calendar Trigger

Tags: swift, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I am on iOS 10.3.2 Beta 4 and xcode 8.3.2. I am attempting to fire a notification at the same time daily, however the notifications never seem to fire. If I do not use the calendar trigger and use the timeinterval trigger they work as expected.

Here is my code

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Daily Notification"
    content.subtitle = ""
    content.body = NSLocalizedString("Hello I am a notification", comment: "Comment")
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour], from: Date())
    dateComponents.hour = 14
    dateComponents.minute = 55

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    NSLog("Setting daily notification - \(dateComponents)")

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "dailyWarning", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Error occurred")
        } else {
            NSLog("Request added successfully: %@", request)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating your trigger like this:

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 14
dateComponents.minute = 55
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true) // Setting repeats to true will trigger the notification daily
```

For more information about why providing just the `hour` and `minutes` is sufficient see the explanation above **Listing 1** in the documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger).

Comment: Using the trigger like this seemed to work better UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: date, repeats: true).

Comment: but I am definitely awarding you the points. thanks for answering!